# is this the correct way to setup route53 to point to a specific rds instance? aws

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

Earlier I was asking about how I can direct a geolocation to use a `read replica rds instance` in other origin and test it.

Route 53 was mentioned and I was then reading the documentation and played around.  But I am not sure if I am doing it right, can someone please give me a hand and let me know if I my steps are right and if I am missing anything?

First, there are four options when I go to route 53.

- dns management
- traffic management (I chose this one)
- availability monitoring
- domain registration

Then I am able to use a visual panel to create the start point -> end point.

[image]

After that is done, I see the tabs on the left.  I clicked hosted zones to create a hosted zone.

[image]

After hosted zone is done, I then went to create a new policy records.

[image]

This is where I ended and not sure if I am doing it correctly that if let's say someone from Canada access into `app.example.com` then it'll actually go to the rds endpoint I added into the traffic policies.

Can someone give me a hand if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think there may be a significant gap in your understanding, here.  What kind of server does `app.example.com` run on, and where is it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it's in  an  ec2 instance on aws

Comment: Okay, and where does that run?  If you wanted an RDS master in, say, us-west-2 and a replica in eu-west-2, you'd need at least one EC2 instance in each of those regions, with the code in each configured to connect to the correct RDS instance, then create latency-based Route 53 records for app.example.com, one for each region (you don't need to pay for policy records for this).  The viewer doesn't go to the RDS endpoint.  The viewer goes to the nearest EC2 instance, which knows (via configuration) which RDS instance it should be using.